# How would I send form data correctly through this post request on the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I need to post the `user_id` and `email` of the user who's doing the file upload.

In Postman, in the `body` -> `form-data` section - all I have's `file` as the `key` and an image as a `value` and it posts successfully (file_path, id, and email get sent to the DB).  I'm not sure how to do it in a way where it isn't form data in terms of `user_id` and `email` so I appended it to the form but it isn't working.

However, in the browser - I get a `500` error which says: `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file`

I've even tried removing `formData.append('user_id', this.state.id);` and `formData.append('email', this.state.email);`

What am I doing wrong?

frontend code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selectedFile: null,
        user_id: null,
        email: ''
    };

    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getId();
    this.getEmail();
}

getId() {
    console.log("inside getId()");
    let user_id = Cookies.get("id");
    this.setState({user_id: user_id}, () => console.log(this.state.user_id));
}

getEmail() {
    console.log("inside getEmail");
    let email = Cookies.get("email");
    this.setState({email: email}, () => console.log(this.state.email));
}

onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] });
}

fileUpload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('user_id', this.state.user_id);
    formData.append('email', this.state.email);

    fetch('http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => { console.error(error) });
}

render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
```

backend controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $id = $request->user()->id;
    $email = $request->user()->email;

   // dd($id, $email);

    $data= [
        'file_path' => $filePath,
        'user_id' => $id,
        'email' => $email
    ];

    DB::table('my.db')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file` isn't very helpful, could you see the exact line it's talking about? If it means `$id = $request->user()->id;`, then it seems like id is not part of `user()`. Maybe try dumping `$request->user()`.

If you are sending `user_id` and `email`, then you can just do `$request->user_id` and `$request->email`. Are you sure there is an active session?

Comment: `id`'s part of `user()`.  I dumped `$request->user()` and it's showing up.  I just need to know how to post the `id` and `email` in my front end code.  In Postman, I'm logging in then uploading a file and it get sent to the DB successfully.  I'm deliberately not including `id` and `email` in Postman and it works just by having the user logged in.